# Is it correct to assume that my package is compatible with a version B, if it is compatible with versions A and C of Python/another packages?

Tags: python, testing, tox

I have just created my own package and would like to publish it on GitHub and PyPi.

I am currently checking the dependencies of the package using [the tox library](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/index.html). My package, for example, uses [the Pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org)

The package tests pass on Pandas 1.1.4 and Pandas 1.3.4. **Is it correct to assume that the tests will also pass on every Pandas version between 1.1.4 and 1.3.4?**

Same question with the Python version. **If the package tests pass on Python 3.8.2 and Python 3.10.0, is it correct to assume that every Python version between these two is compatible with my code?**

**If the assumption is incorrect, is there a way to automate the process with the tox library?**

Just in case, I will list other package dependencies:

- matplotlib
- beautifulsoup4
- requests
- numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot assume your package will work for a Python or a e.g. Pandas version you do not test.

This means, if you really want to make sure your package works with all combinations, you need to test them.

`tox` is a great tool for that.

You need to use `factors` in `tox`.

Especially the Django community use this feature a lot, e.g.:

https://github.com/jazzband/django-auditlog/blob/3dee9f1555239ae9c4a50afeaa487547247d2d96/tox.ini

And here is the link to the relevant part in the `tox` documentation:

https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html?highlight=factors#factors-and-factor-conditional-settings

For testing this matrix on GitHub, I recommend to use this `tox` plugin

https://github.com/ymyzk/tox-gh-actions

Disclaimer: I am one of the `tox` maintainers.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I understand now what I should do. I have another question: should I only test minor versions of Python or should I test every bugfix version too? For example, if I want to check if my code is compatible with Python 3.8, then should I test Python 3.8.1, 3.8.2 etc.? It would be a really time-consuming approach, so maybe should I just pick one of the 3.8 versions and test everything on it (e.g. Python 3.8.12 - the most recent bugfix)? In case of other packages (Pandas etc.), I assume that I should test every bugfix version. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What level of certainty do you need? Point releases are not _supposed_ to contain breaking changes (for projects that follow semver), but it's not impossible that one will. And when there's an unintentional breaking change in a point release it can be fixed in a subsequent point release. I'd look at how much time/money/reputation is riding on having a correct answer and use that to guide construction of your test matrix.

Comment: Also, there's nothing that says you can't tell your users you tested X.Y.0 and X.Y.3 and let them draw their own conclusions about X.Y.1 and X.Y.2.