# How to use tox in an existing python package with requirements and setup

Tags: python, tox

I have a python/django app.

I do have requirements.txt, requirements_dev.txt and setup.py like this:

**requirements.txt**

```
a_package_from_our_pypi_server
django~=2.2.3
django-filter
djangorestframework~=3.10.1
django-restql==0.13.1
requests==2.24.0
Pillow~=8.2
```

**requirements_dev.txt**

```
-r requirements.txt

coverage==5.2.1
factory-boy==3.2.0
# Syntax and style checkers
black==20.8b1
isort==5.8.0
pre-commit==2.12.1
```

**setup.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

import mypackage
requirements = open('requirements.txt').readlines()

setup(
    name='mypackage',
    install_requires=requirements,

    . . . a lot of other parameters
)
```

1. What is the way to use tox to test against for example different python, Django and Django Rest Framework versions?
2. What package versions should I require in the `install_requires` in the `setup.py` after testing against versions?
3. How do I define `install_requires` in setup.py and requirements.txt?

The problem I have, is that the package is an API, so I do have a few packages that are required to be installed and not only one or two as I see in a lot of packages. That is why I do have `install_requires=requirements` in `setup.py`. And I would like to continue to use a practice like this one, and do not have to sync a lot of packages both in requirements and setup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to assume that my package is compatible with a version B, if it is compatible with versions A and C of Python/another packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69874885/is-it-correct-to-assume-that-my-package-is-compatible-with-a-version-b-if-it-is)

Comment: I have answered a very similar question yesterday, see comment above.

Comment: Hi @JürgenGmach. I added more questions to the end. What do I do with the rest of the dependencies I do have besides django and drf? How do I configure install_requires?

Answer (score 0):

ad 1) As I already mentioned, you need to use factors in tox.

Especially the Django community use this feature a lot, e.g.:

https://github.com/jazzband/django-auditlog/blob/3dee9f1555239ae9c4a50afeaa487547247d2d96/tox.ini

And here is the link to the relevant part in the tox documentation:

https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html?highlight=factors#factors-and-factor-conditional-settings

For testing this matrix on GitHub, I recommend to use this tox plugin

https://github.com/ymyzk/tox-gh-actions

ad 2) and ad 3) There is a lot of confusion about `setup.py` and `requirements.txt`. One reason for that is that you need to differentiate whether you have a library or an app.

A app should always be installed with `pip install -r requirements.txt`, a library with `pip install library` which invokes `setup.py`.

In the `install-requires` you only put the name of the dependencies, not the version numbers, ie

`install_requires=["django", "django-filters", ...]`

In order to get the exact version numbers for requirements.txt, you could use a tool like `pip-tools` which brings `pip-compile` along.

With `pip-compile` you generate a requirements.txt with all direct, and indirect dependencies.

You should test against requirements.txt and from time to time update it via `pip-compile`.

Comment: I am using the project as a library (I have the sdist on my own pypi server, and another app add 'library' to it's own requirements.txt, so basically installing as a library 'pip install library'). But then for local development I do install 'pip install -r requirements.txt' . So, if I use pinned versions for local dev, how can I be sure that the library will work when installed with less restrictive versions in setup? . Side note: I see that projects, like DRF, write at least a min package version in install_requires. So it is not a good practice to